# Inheritance in Javascript : child object still calling its parent method

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm trying to do a simple practice in Javascript Inheritance but I cannot understand what is going on with this code:

```
function person() {
    this.firstName = 'asdf';
    this.lastName = 'asdfasdf';
    this.showName = function () {
        console.log(this.firstName);
    }
}

function employee() {
    person.call(this);
}
employee.prototype = person.prototype;
employee.prototype.showName = function showName() {
    console.log = "I am an employee";
};

var p = new person();
p.showName();
var e = new employee();
e.showName();
```

In this code the `e.showName` is still calling its parent method, despite the fact that I was trying to override the method. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Take a look here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/4ctbg7ey . As I understood you should override methods not in prototype but in target class itself

Comment: I've edited your tags: you're not talking about "PrototypeJS" but about "prototype" (standard JS approach to inheritance)

Comment: Maybe the following answer can be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). JavaScript runtime will look for the nearest definition of requested property.

Since you're defining `showName` in `person` during the constructor call, you're defining a `showName` in the object rather than in the prototype. Runtime will look for the nearest property called `showName` and it'll find `this.showName` before `prototype.showName`.

Just try to define `showName` in `person` in the prototype instead of in the object itself:

```
function person() {
  ...
}

person.prototype = { 
      showName: function() {
          ...
      }
}
```

...and you'll get the expected result!

### In other words...

Let's say you've the following JavaScript constructor function:

```
var A = function() {
    this.doX = function() {};
};

A.prototype = {
   doX: function() { }
};
```

What function will be called if I create an instance of `A`?

```
var instance = new A();
instance.doX(); // ?????
```

The `doX()` added during the construction time will be the one called by the runtime instead of the one defined in the prototype.

In fact, the `doX()` defined in the `A` constructor is equivalent to just doing the following declaration:

```
var instance = new A();
instance.doX = function() {};
```

The `this` keyword inside the `A` constructor is a reference of the instantiated object, thus it's the same declaring it inside or outside the constructor - actually there's a single difference: if you declare outside the constructor, not all `A` instances will own the whole property... -.

At the end of the day, properties declared in the object hide ones declared in the prototype, and this is what happened in your code, because `employee` calls the `person` constructor with the `this` reference of `employee`, meaning that `showName` in `person` will hide the one declared in the `employee` prototype.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person() {
  this.name = 'Jack';
  this.age = 72;  

  this.showName = function() {
    return 'Person: ' + this.name;
  }
}

function Student() {
  Person.call(this);  

  this.showName = function() {
    return 'Student: ' + this.name;  
  }
}

var p = new Person();
alert(p.showName()); // Shows 'Person: Jack'
var s = new Student();
alert(s.showName()); // Shows 'Student: Jack'
```

Comment: An answer stating showname would be better on Person.prototype and setting Student.prototype equal to Person.prototype is not correctly inheriting may have been better. You now solved the problem by ditching the prototype completely

Answer (score 0):

Prototype object is the parent object of the person

so you are overwriting the prototype showName() with the person showName() so the out put is the person firstname is printing in the console.